# The T in "stair" and D in "dare"

Tags: pronunciation

I checked that their pronunciations are /ster/ and /der/
But I can't hear the difference between them!
Can anyone tell me the difference and how to pronounce them separately?

Comment: There won’t necessarily be any difference. Initial /d/ is usually at least partially voiced, but it can also be unvoiced, in which case it is exactly the same as the unaspirated [t] in _stair_.

Comment: Would people be able to hear the difference? Or can they feel the difference when they pronounce? Thank you!

Comment: If we assume that _dare_ is being said in such a way that the /d/ is **not** voiced, then people will **think** they’re able to hear the difference because they know that _stare_ has a /t/ and _dare_ has a /d/—and the third player, _tare_ has an initial /t/, which is forcefully aspirated and slightly affricated, thus very different from the other two. However, if you record _stare_ and _dare_ and use a computer to cut away the [s] bit of _stare_, then people will almost always be completely unable to tell the difference.

Comment: Some people would hear the difference right away, and others wouldn't know they were hearing anything different. In English /t/ and /d/ neutralize in many environments in speech, and after initial /s/ is one of them. We deal with this by spelling and transcribing this as /st/, but in fact the allophone of /t/ used there is virtually indistinguishable from the allophone of /d/ that would appear in initial /sd/, just as the allophone of /t/ that shows up in many speakers _bottle_ is in fact a glottal stop. Phonemes are generalizations; individual phonation is individual.

Comment: Perhaps you should also say where you are.  This T may be pronounced differently in London than in Chicago.

Comment: I find it incredible that one could not hear the difference between "stair" and "dare" when properly pronounced.  ("Properly pronounced" meaning spoken by a US Midwesterner.)  As I've mentioned before, I suspect such differences are as much an issue of discrimination by the listener as they are diction by the speaker.  If you're raised in a culture that does not differentiate then you don't hear the difference.

Comment: @Hot Licks: the OP is not asking about the difference between "stair" and "dare" (there's an /s/ in one that's missing from the other); he's asking about the difference between the /t/ and the /d/ in those words. Namely, the difference between *"it's stark"* and *"it's dark"*, which are much harder to tell apart.

Comment: @PeterShor - OK, I'll admit that those are pretty hard to tell apart.

Comment: You have a very good ear!

Comment: Are there any native English words beginning with the phonemes /sd-/? I wonder if there's a phonotactic rule which prohibits it?

Comment: According to [the Wikipedia page on English phonotactics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics) there is in fact a rule which prevents it: "The second consonant in a complex onset must not be a voiced obstruent"

Comment: stair and dare has the same phonemes except the s, as: tear (rip) and dare. So basically, it's the difference between t and d.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/620545/2085).

Answer (score 4):

The initial consonants in ‘tear’ (the verb) and ‘dare’ are distinguished mainly by the fact that initial /t/ is unvoiced and slightly aspirated while initial /d/ is slightly voiced and not aspirated. The /t/ in ‘stair’ is not aspirated, so it is distinguished from /d/ only with regard to voicing. The voicing of /d/ is however so slight that there is virtually no audible difference between the two sounds.

Comment: English doesn't phonemically distinguish aspirated and unaspirated sounds, but it can often be more obvious than voicing, which results in tricky examples like this where the [t] and [d] are so very similar.

Comment: @curiousdannii Maybe not phonemically, but more air comes out with tear than with dare.

Answer (score 2):

The two sounds are very similar, but /t/ is the unvoiced equivalent of /d/. Many languages have both sounds. Listen for the voiced component as you would when dealing with /b/ vs. /p/, /g/ vs. /k/, and other such consonant sounds.

Comment: Would people be able to hear the difference? Or can they feel the difference when they pronounce the word themselves? Thank you!

Comment: Try practicing with a friend who speaks English natively on words where the only difference is that consonant: dare/tear, dale/tale, dart/tart, dell/tell, dent/tent, dip/tip, dowel/towel, drain/train, dune/tune. Can you hear the difference when your friend says these words? Can you feel the difference when you pronounce these words correctly?

Comment: I was considering fdb's answer and realized that, as in other languages, the difference is often distinguished by context. Of the word pairs I provided above, you likely wouldn't be able to replace one with the other in a sentence and have it make sense. Don't worry: English isn't the only language that does this.

Comment: You can hear the difference because hearing is conditioned by context. If you recorded it and chopped off the initial /s/ or looked at a spectrogram, there might not be a difference. People don't normally feel a sound when they're pronouncing; whether they can detect a difference in their own speech and explain what it is would probably depend on their training, but based on studying linguistics, naive intuitions about sounds are often incorrect.